# Why is my Prim's algorithm not returning the proper MST?

Tags: java, prims-algorithm

I apologize in advance if this code appears to be long, but I am still a beginner with Java and are having a difficult time implementing Prim's algorithm. When I submit my script on vocareum, I am getting that an improper MST is getting returned. I have been continually tracing through my script and cannot seem to pick up the reason as to why I am getting this error.

If anyone has any advice it would be greatly appreciated! Again, I am still a beginner and may be missing something obvious here.

See below for part 1 of my script (which is the part of the assignment in which we are suppose to be writing). This is the "GraphAlgorithms.java" file.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Your implementation of Prim's algorithm.
 */
public class GraphAlgorithms {

    /**
     * Runs Prim's algorithm on the given graph and returns the Minimum
     * Spanning Tree (MST) in the form of a set of Edges. If the graph is
     * disconnected and therefore no valid MST exists, return null.
     *
     * You may assume that the passed in graph is undirected. In this framework,
     * this means that if (u, v, 3) is in the graph, then the opposite edge
     * (v, u, 3) will also be in the graph, though as a separate Edge object.
     *
     * The returned set of edges should form an undirected graph. This means
     * that every time you add an edge to your return set, you should add the
     * reverse edge to the set as well. This is for testing purposes. This
     * reverse edge does not need to be the one from the graph itself; you can
     * just make a new edge object representing the reverse edge.
     *
     * You may assume that there will only be one valid MST that can be formed.
     *
     * You should NOT allow self-loops or parallel edges in the MST.
     *
     * You may import/use java.util.PriorityQueue, java.util.Set, and any
     * class that implements the aforementioned interface.
     *
     * DO NOT modify the structure of the graph. The graph should be unmodified
     * after this method terminates.
     *
     * The only instance of java.util.Map that you may use is the adjacency
     * list from graph. DO NOT create new instances of Map for this method
     * (storing the adjacency list in a variable is fine).
     *
     * You may assume that the passed in start vertex and graph will not be null.
     * You may assume that the start vertex exists in the graph.
     *
     * @param <T>   The generic typing of the data.
     * @param start The vertex to begin Prims on.
     * @param graph The graph we are applying Prims to.
     * @return The MST of the graph or null if there is no valid MST.
     */
    public static <T> Set<Edge<T>> prims(Vertex<T> start, Graph<T> graph) {
        if (start == null || graph == null
                || !graph.getAdjList().containsKey(start)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        PriorityQueue<Edge<T>> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
        Set<Vertex<T>> visited = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Edge<T>> edgeset = new HashSet<>();
        for (Edge<T> edge : graph.getEdges()){
            if (edge.getU() == start){
                queue.add(edge);
            }
        }
        visited.add(start);
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Edge<T> temp = queue.remove();
            if (!visited.contains(temp.getV())) {
                edgeset.add(new Edge<>(temp.getU(), temp.getV(), temp.getWeight()));
                visited.add(temp.getV());
                for (Edge<T> edge : graph.getEdges()) {
                    if (temp.getV() == edge.getU()) {
                        queue.add(edge);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (edgeset.size() < graph.getVertices().size() - 1) {
            return null;
        }
        return edgeset;
    }
}
```

The following scripts are classes in which we are provided with and are explicitly told not to change. These may or may not be necessary to dig too deeply into as only a few of the methods are currently being used in my script above. But I attached all of them for reference. Below is the "Edge.java" file.

```
/**
 * Class representing a directed edge from u to v.
 *
 * DO NOT EDIT THIS CLASS!!
 *
 * @author CS 1332 TAs
 * @version 1.0
 */

public class Edge<T> implements Comparable<Edge<? super T>> {

    private Vertex<T> u;
    private Vertex<T> v;
    private int weight;

    /**
     * Creates a directed edge from vertex u to vertex v. Any single edge is
     * always directed, so if you're trying to create an undirected edge, you
     * must create the edges (u, v, weight) and (v, u, weight) when creating the
     * graph.
     *
     * @param u The start vertex of the edge.
     * @param v The end vertex of the edge.
     * @param weight The weight value of the edge.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if any of the arguments are null.
     */
    public Edge(Vertex<T> u, Vertex<T> v, int weight) {
        if (u == null || v == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arguments cannot be null.");
        }
        this.u = u;
        this.v = v;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the weight.
     *
     * @return The weight.
     */
    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the starting vertex (u).
     *
     * @return The starting vertex (u).
     */
    public Vertex<T> getU() {
        return u;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the ending vertex(v).
     *
     * @return The ending vertex (v).
     */
    public Vertex<T> getV() {
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o != null && o instanceof Edge<?>) {
            Edge<?> e = (Edge<?>) o;
            return weight == e.weight && u.equals(e.u) && v.equals(e.v);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return u.hashCode() ^ v.hashCode() ^ weight;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Edge<? super T> e) {
        return weight - e.getWeight();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Edge from " + u + " to " + v + " with weight " + weight;
    }
}
```

Below is the "Graph.java" file.

```
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    
    /**
     * A class representing a directed graph, with a vertex set, edge set, and
     * an adjacency list.
     *
     * DO NOT EDIT THIS CLASS!!!
     *
     * @author CS 1332 TAs
     * @version 1.0
     */
    public class Graph<T> {
    
        private Set<Vertex<T>> vertices;
        private Set<Edge<T>> edges;
        private Map<Vertex<T>, List<VertexDistance<T>>> adjList;
    
        /**
         * Builds the graph from a set of vertices and an edge list. All edges in
         * the edge set are assumed to be directed, so if you want to create an
         * undirected edge, the edge set must contain both the forward and backwards
         * edges.
         *
         * @param vertices The vertex set.
         * @param edges The edge set.
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException If any of the arguments are null or if
         * the vertex set doesn't contain all of the vertices.
         */
        public Graph(Set<Vertex<T>> vertices, Set<Edge<T>> edges) {
            if (vertices == null || edges == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arguments cannot be null.");
            }
    
            this.vertices = new HashSet<>(vertices);
            this.edges = new HashSet<>(edges);
            adjList = new HashMap<>();
            for (Vertex<T> v : vertices) {
                adjList.put(v, new ArrayList<>());
            }
    
            for (Edge<T> e : edges) {
                if (adjList.containsKey(e.getU())) {
                    adjList.get(e.getU()).add(new VertexDistance<>(e.getV(), e.getWeight()));
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Vertex set must contain all vertices of the graph.");
                }
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Gets the vertex set.
         *
         * @return The vertex set.
         */
        public Set<Vertex<T>> getVertices() {
            return vertices;
        }
    
        /**
         * Gets the edge set.
         *
         * @return The edge set.
         */
        public Set<Edge<T>> getEdges() {
            return edges;
        }
    
        /**
         * Gets the adjacency list.
         *
         * @return The adjacency list.
         */
        public Map<Vertex<T>, List<VertexDistance<T>>> getAdjList() {
            return adjList;
        }
    }
```

Below is the "Vertex.java" file.

```
/**
 * Class representing a vertex.
 *
 * DO NOT EDIT THIS CLASS!!!
 *
 * @author CS 1332 TAs
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class Vertex<T> {

    private T data;

    /**
     * Creates a Vertex object holding the given data.
     *
     * @param data The object that is stored in this Vertex.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If data is null.
     */
    public Vertex(T data) {
        if (data == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data cannot be null.");
        }
        this.data = data;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the data.
     *
     * @return The data of this vertex.
     */
    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o != null && o instanceof Vertex) {
            return data.equals(((Vertex<?>) o).data);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return data.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data.toString();
    }
}
```

And lastly, the "VertexDistance.java" file.

```
/**
 * Class to store a vertex in a graph and an integer associated with it
 * representing the distance to this vertex from some other vertex.
 *
 * DO NOT EDIT THIS CLASS!!!
 *
 * @author CS 1332 TAs
 * @version 1.0
 */
public final class VertexDistance<T> implements Comparable<VertexDistance<? super T>> {

    private final Vertex<T> vertex;
    private final int distance;

    /**
     * Creates a pairing of vertex and distance to that vertex.
     *
     * @param vertex the Vertex to be stored.
     * @param distance the integer representing the distance to this Vertex
     *                 from the previous Vertex.
     */
    public VertexDistance(Vertex<T> vertex, int distance) {
        this.vertex = vertex;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the vertex.
     *
     * @return The vertex.
     */
    public Vertex<T> getVertex() {
        return vertex;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the distance
     *
     * @return The distance.
     */
    public int getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o != null && o instanceof VertexDistance<?>) {
            VertexDistance<?> e = (VertexDistance<?>) o;
            return distance == e.distance && vertex.equals(e.vertex);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return vertex.hashCode() ^ distance;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(VertexDistance<? super T> pair) {
        return this.getDistance() - pair.getDistance();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pair with vertex " + vertex + " and distance " + distance;
    }
}
```

Comment: TL;DR (You could use `record`, i.e. for the immutable `Edge` or `VertexDistance` class. It would save much code.) You are using `==` instead of `.equals`.  That might be correct, when there is just one instance of equal objects; but it is an infamous beginner's error.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, use `equals` instead of `==` since `equals` compares the content of the objects, whereas `==` compares the object references. `==` returns true if and only if you are comparing exactly same objects.

Also notice that it is stated in the problem description that

> The returned set of edges should form an undirected graph. This means that every time you add an edge to your return set, you should add the reverse edge to the set as well.

Your algorithm seems correct, probably you should just add this line:

```java
edgeset.add(new Edge<>(temp.getV(), temp.getU(), temp.getWeight()));
```

Let me know if it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Yes that worked! I am now at least getting a better score. I am still however getting this error message.                                                                                                                       [Test Failure: prims] [-0.67] : MST was found when no MST should have been found. 

[Test Failure: unmodified] [-0.67] : Graph structure could not be validated for the following method(s) due to early test failure(s): prims. 
Not exactly sure why about this one. But at least I am now getting a much better score than before.

Comment: Hi @Jdonza, could you make sure that you change both lines where you used ```==``` instead of ```equals```? I suppose the first error says that you returned a MST although you shouldn't have returned any. That would be great if you could modify your question and reflect the changes you made on your code so that we can follow easily if there is still any error in the code.